# Использование функций

Tags: php, функции

Написал скрипт для облегчения скачивания файлов с файлообменников(ФО). Сейчас устроено так: 
Пользователь через форму отправляет ссылку скрипту, скрипт проверяет через "preg_match" название ФО, и для каждого ФО свой метод получения прямой ссылки на файл. Весь скрипт построено на условиях if:

```
if(preg_match("/site1/", $url)){
Получение url
}
if(preg_match("/site2/", $url)){
}
if(preg_match("/site3/", $url)){
}
if(preg_match("/site4/", $url)){
}
```

Как сделать это все через функции - читал про них, но так и не пойму до сих пор как их использовать.

Comment: А что именно вы хотите сделать через функции?

Comment: Если вам нужно проверить что сайт - одно из значений, preg_match - явный перебор. Можно просто искать домен в строке.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Получение прямой ссылки, я предполагаю что функции более облегчают и оптимизируют код.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов а можно подробнее?

Comment: Функцию предпочтительно использовать, если код выполняется множество раз. В данной задаче такая надобность отсутствует. Для оптимизации лучше заменить preg_match на strpos. Использование функций в любом языке программирования аналогично. Раньше не программировал? Читай учебники, справочники... В принципе, ничего сложного: оборачиваешь тот же код в функцию так: function funkciya() {Код} и вызываешь funkciya();

Comment: @Дмитрий хм, разве strpos подходит для поиска домена?

Comment: @edvardpotter Еще как подходит: if(strpos($perem, 'sait.ru') !== false) {} elseif(strpos($perem, 'sait2.ru') !== false) {} и. т.д.

Comment: Вообще, конкретно имя сайта можно проверять так: ; $host = parse_url('полный URL', PHP_URL_HOST); switch($host) { case 'sait': Это сайт ... break; case 'sait2': Это сайт 2; break; default: ХЗ, что за сайт, не знаю такого;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

верхние коментарии хороши в вашем случае функцию сделел бы такую.

```
    function file ($url){
      switch ($url){
         case(preg_match("/site1/", $url)):
           return Получение url;
        break;
        case(preg_match("/site2/", $url)):
           return Получение url;
        break;
        case(preg_match("/site3/", $url)):
           return Получение url;
        break;
        case(preg_match("/site4/", $url)):
           return Получение url;
        break;
     }
}
$urlThe=file(http://...)
```

где "http://..." это адрес вашего обменика, он передаеться в функцию file в виде парамерта $url обрабатывается функцией и потом через return передается переменой  $urlThe. И если много раз используете if то мне кажеться целесообразнее использовать switch http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: Возможно мой вопрос прозвучит глупо, но как в case добавлять большие участки кода?

Comment: @edvardpotter Честно ни когда не обрашал внимание на болльшие участки кода в swith но вроде выполняется все до break в карайнем случае запихните в теже переменые весь код и веред или через функции.

Comment: @edvardpotter: нельзя ли выделять эти большие участки кода в отдельные методы/функции?